# php: echo structural information

Tags: javascript, php, html, arrays

I have a:

1. html page with dynamically generated `div`s, and send request to a php file via `XMLHttpRequest`;
2. the php file, which fetch data from some mysql database, and organizes the data into a 2-dimensional array (e.g. each row contains the height, weight, etc, of a sample person). Elements of the array are texts (so there are all kinds of special characters)

I want to return the 2d-array of text back to Html. The texts in one row of the array should go to one `div` (e.g. one `div` displays one person's information).

There are 3 possible solutions I can think of:

1. Combine the 2d-array of texts into one huge string and echo it back ==> divide it apart on the Html end.
2. For each `div` send individual `XMLHttpRequest` to the php ==> php fetches one array of data and echo them back in one single string, and let html to deal with the string.

3) Abandon the mysql data base, use XML file to store?

Question: I wonder if there are more elegant ways of doing this (echo structural data)? And if I were to take the above methods, what are good delimiters to use?

Comment: you may want to read about sending AJAX request with JSON.

Comment: If you have an array in PHP, use `json_encode()` to encode it and send it to your client as a JSON string. Very easy. Reference is [here](http://www.php.net/json_encode)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the best you can do is to organize your information in a PHP array so it looks something like this:

```
array("person1" => array(
                        age=>22
                        genre=>male
                    )
     )
```

After that you can run json_encode your array, set the response headers to JSON and echo the json encoded response. Check [this example](http://eosrei.net/articles/2011/12/basic-json-requestresponse-php)

With this, you can easily read in the front end the json response and show the information that you want for each div by using javascript.